# Error fetch_assoc() on boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

Requiero poder modificar un registro mediante una tabla, pero sucede que al momento de querer ejecutar la acción del botón me envía un error.

Anteriormente había hecho una prueba con una tabla de 15 registros más o menos y sí funcionaba, pero cuando intenté hacer éste que tiene más de mil registros me mostró el error.

Ésta es mi tabla:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table display table-striped table-responsive">
       <thead style="color: #5acbf5">
        <tr>
            <th>Sinatura</th>
            <th>Titulo</th>
            <th>Autor</th>
            <th><a href="nuevo1.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Nuevo</button></a></th>

       </tr>
    </thead>

        <tbody>
    <?php 
                      include "conexion.php";
                      $sentencia = "SELECT * FROM books";
                      $resultado = $conexion->query($sentencia) or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
                      while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo "<tr style='color: #7dce30'>";
                          echo "<td>"; echo $fila['Sinatura']; echo "</td>";
                          echo "<td>"; echo $fila['Titulo']; echo "</td>";
                          echo "<td>"; echo $fila['Autor1']; echo "</td>";

                          echo "<td><a href='modificar1.php?no=".$fila['ID']."'> <button type='button' class= 'btn btn-success'>Modificar</button></a></td>";

                          echo "<td><a href='eliminar.php?no=".$fila['ID']."'> <button type='button' class= 'btn btn-danger'>Eliminar</button></a></td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\operations\modificar1.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\operations\modificar1.php(3): ConsultaProducto('1') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\operations\modificar1.php on line 9

Y en esa parte tengo hecho:

```
<?php 
//modificar1.php
$consulta = ConsultaProducto($_GET['no']);

function ConsultaProducto($no_prod){
  include 'conexion.php';
  $sentencia = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE no='".$no_prod."' ";
  $resultado = $conexion->query($sentencia);
  $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc(); //Aquí es donde me marca el error

  return[
    $fila['Sinatura'],
    $fila['Titulo'],
    $fila['Autor1']
  ];
}
```

Por lo tanto, no sé qué hacer... intenté con `array` pero tampoco funcionó.

Esta parte está dividida en `modificar1` y `modificar2`, en donde el otro es:

```
<?php //modificar2.php
ModificarProducto($_POST['no'], $_POST['Sinatura'], $_POST['Titulo'], $_POST['Autor1']);

function ModificarProducto($no, $id_prod, $nom, $descrip){
    include 'conexion.php';
    $sentencia="UPDATE books SET Sinatura='".$id_prod."', Titulo='".$nom."', Autor1='".$descrip."' WHERE no='".$no."' ";
    $conexion->query($sentencia) or die ("ERROR al actualizar datos");
}
```

Comment: Asumo que usas `mysqli`. ¿Por qué no usas consultas preparadas? ¿Por qué no usas `$conexion->query(...) or die(...)` igual que en el código del principio? En resumen: la consulta ha fallado por no hacerla correctamente y ésta te devuelve `false` un booleano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El significado de `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean` proviene de no haber tenido en cuenta que `$resultado` podría valer `false` (un valor booleano, no un recurso mysqli) en caso de que se produjera un error en la llamada a `query()`.

Un dato booleano no tiene propiedades ni métodos (como el método llamado `fetch_assoc()` que tratas de usar). De ahí ese mensaje: "no puedes llamar a una función miembro de un dato de tipo booleano".

Puedes averiguar qué falla en tu código si lo blindas correctamente ante situaciones de error. Además, deberías usar consultas preparadas para escapar caracteres SQL (como las comillas) o, al menos, usar la función [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string) para preparar la cadena para ser insertada en una consulta SQL de manera correcta:

```
function ConsultaProducto($no_prod) {
  /* Es preferible require sore include para que finalice la ejecución
      si no encuentra el archivo */
  require_once 'conexion.php';
  /* Para facilitar la lectura asigno a una nueva variable el contenido
      de $no_prod escapado con real_escape_string */
  $no_prod_sql = $conexion->real_escape_string($no_prod);
  /* Puede que $no_prod sea un número, por lo que se puede escapar
      o bien comprobar que sea un número válido (y no una cadena vacía) */
  $sentencia = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE no='$no_prod_sql'";
  $resultado = $conexion->query($sentencia);
  /* Si $resultado vale false es porque ocurrió un error en la consulta */
  if ($resultado === false) {
    die($conexion->error);
  }
  /* OJO: Si no hay ninguna fila que obtener ¡$fila valdrá false! */
  $fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
  return [
    $fila['Sinatura'],
    $fila['Titulo'],
    $fila['Autor1'],
  ];
}
```